# How can I import a go module which is inside a subfolder?

Tags: go

I published a go module in github: `github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module`. The `go.mod` file is in `apps` folder rather than root folder.

When I import it from another project, I run `go get github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module@0.0.2` and it runs successfully. However, I get the error when compiling:

main.go

```golang
import (
log "github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger"
)

log.Test()
```

```
main.go:11:2: no required module provides package github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger; to add it:
        go get github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger
```

I get error when import the sub folder:

```
> go get github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger@v0.0.2
go: module github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module@v0.0.2 found, but does not contain package github.com/zhaoyi0113/test-go-module/apps/logger
```

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

after Go 1.18 you can use go work command to enable working with multi-modules in the root folder

checkout this tutorial for more
https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces